# Take bitmap from camera to use in another activity

Tags: android

I am new to asking questions here and might be doing this completely wrong so please bear with me. I am working on a fun, self-use android app with the objective of being able to take a picture with the camera, and turn this picture into a jigsaw puzzle which can be assembled. I am modifying this project here:

https://github.com/bravelittlescientist/android-jigsaw-puzzle

so that a custom picture can be used for the puzzle. 
In the launcher activity called "PictureActivity" I have two buttons, one to open up the camera, and one to start the new activity called "PuzzleActivity" with the bitmap taken by the camera in the intent.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.bTakePic:
                    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
                    break;
            case R.id.bCreatePuzz:
                    Intent j = new Intent( this, PuzzleActivity.class);
                    j.putExtra("IMAGE", bmp);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
            }
    }
```

The puzzle is assembled based on a method in the "ExampleJigsawConfigurations" class. Currently it uses a default image of a cat which is saved in the project's drawable folder. The location of this image is stored as an integer value in a bundle which is later converted into a bitmap and drawn onto the canvas. I can retrieve the bitmap from the first activity with getParcelableExtras(), but only in the PuzzleActivity. I need a way to make the bitmap for the puzzle be set to the picture taken by the camera.

I am sure that there is probably a simple solution to this, but I am not the most experienced programmer so any help would be much appreciated.